# Get GUID from vb6 dll classes

Tags: .net, com, vb6, guid

I have a Challenge here :)...
I have a vb6 dll with say 4 classes.
I need from my .net winform app to be able to get the GUID from all these classes (4 guids).

Thanks.

Comment: Your question needs a lot more details in order to be answerable. What exactly are you talking about? What GUIDs? What do you mean by "get" them?

Comment: Are these DLLs actually COM DLLs?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dll is registered the `CLSID` GUIDs are listed in `HKCR` under a `ProgID`

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
  TheServerName.PublicObjectName
     CLSID
       [default] = {...}
```